# 407 Proxy Error Encountered with Fusion Tables

Tags: google-fusion-tables

When I try to use the docid in place of the table id I get a 407 proxy error. My understanding is that you don't need to authenticate for selecting records, only for inserts, updates, and deletes. When I use the table id, the sql query hangs. I noticed these errors in the Firebug console window.

I am able to receive data from both tables (levels_a.txt & levels_b.txt) when the tables aren't merged. The same isn't true when they are merged. Please see below for my code.

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart", "annotatedtimeline"] });

var map, layer;
var tableID = 3013978;
//var tableID = "1RWnj3geWmOXHcedu8RUeyb1v4ZjZz3YWNpK0MDs";
var location_column = 'geometry';
var name, PID;
var chart;

var jqXHR;
var formatter_long;
var dt;
var rows;
var plot;
var scatter_chart;
var g;

function initialize() {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.760861, -98.813876);
    var myOptions = {
        center: latlng,
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [
                                            google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                                            google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                                            google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                                            google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
                                        ],

            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        },
        overviewMapControl: true,
        overviewMapControlOptions: {
            opened: true
        }

    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: location_column,
            from: tableID
        }
    });
    layer.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function (e) {
        name = e.row['name'].value;
        PID = e.row['WELL_PID'].value;
        drawChart(PID, name);
    });
}

function drawChart(PID, name) {
/*
  var queryURL = "http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=";
  var queryTail = '&jsonCallback=?';
  var whereClause = "WHERE 'WELL_PID'=" + PID; // table id 3004502
  var query = "SELECT 'Date','Level' FROM 3004502 " + whereClause;
  var queryText = encodeURIComponent(query);
  */

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
  var queryUrlHead = 'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=';
  var queryUrlTail = '&jsonCallback=?';

  var whereClause = "WHERE 'WELL_PID'=" + PID; // table id 3004502
  var query = "SELECT 'Date','Level' FROM 1RrJI_dWPjrmJ7A6xD_GcZ3nxIso9ZTvOPWp0suI " + whereClause;

  var queryurl = encodeURI(queryUrlHead + query + queryUrlTail);

  var jqxhr = $.get(queryurl, dataHandler, "jsonp");
  //console.log(jqxhr);

  /*
  var rows;
  var items = [];
  var arr = [];
  var str;


  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: queryURL + queryText + queryTail,

      cache: false,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',

      success: function (data) {

          rows = data.table.rows;

          for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
              var temp = rows[i];
              var this_date;

              items.push([parseDate(temp[0]), temp[1]]);
          }


          processData(items);

      },
      error: function () { alert("Please wait until chart loads before clicking on another well location."); }
  });
  */
}

function dataHandler(d) {

   var items = [];
   var rows = d.table.rows;

    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var temp = rows[i];
        var this_date;

        items.push([parseDate(temp[0]), temp[1]]);
    }
    processData(items);

}

function processData(res) {

    var options = {
        strokeWidth: 0.0,
        displayAnnotations: true,
        labelsKMB: false,
        rollPeriod: 14,
        showRangeSelector: true,
        connectSeparatedPoints: false,
        drawPoints: true,
        stepPlot: false,
        pointSize: 1,
        digitsAfterDecimal: 3
    };


    var dat = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dat.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    dat.addColumn('number', 'Water Level');

    console.log(res.toString());

    if (res.toString() === "") {
        alert("Sorry, there is no data available for this well. Please check back at a later time.");
         $("#dg_div").empty();
    } else {
        dat.addRows(res);
        if (g) {
            g.destroy();
        }
        g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("dg_div"), dat, options);    
    } 
}
```

I would like to perform the following joins:

```
geography.kml
name | geometry | description

well_name_and_PID.csv
WELL_PID | Name_Short

levels_a.txt
WELL_PID | Date | Level

levels_b.txt
WELL_PID | Date | Level

Joins:

[geography.kml].name -> [well_name_and_PID.csv].Name_Short
[well_name_and_PID.csv].WELL_PID -> [levels_a.txt].WELL_PID
[well_name_and_PID.csv].WELL_PID -> [levels_b.txt].WELL_PID
```

The rationale behind having two level files is that this file would othewise exceed the 100 meg table cap. These two files contain similar information.

As usual, any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: How many rows are in the table? It looks like this was a many-to-many merge, which Fusion Tables isn't handling well. What are the ids of the base tables used to create the merge?

Comment: The table doesn't appear to be merged correctly. In the merged table (table id: 3014066) I have 895655 rows. The base tables used to create the merge are as follows: (table id: 2977597) - 3832362 rows, (table id: 2977838) - 3836776 rows, and (table id: 2994442) - 569 rows. I have tried to create the merge using the Fusion table GUI where I have used both the table id and docid.

Comment: I believe I found a solution to this issue. It seems that you can import a csv table of 100 megs then add additional rows from the same file to the table. I was under the impression that a given table could not exceed 100 megs in size. As a result, I don't need to split my 180 meg file into 2 but keep it as one. However, I have a questions regarding duplicate values. Is fusion tables smart enough to not duplicate values while adding additional rows after the import? Thanks again Kathryn for your suggestions, as always you have been very helpful, keep up the great work!

Comment: Fusion Tables does not keep track of duplicates and will import all data.